# If someone forcefully sacrificed me... Would I go to hell?

Tags: shaitan, soul, sacrifice, jahannam

Assalamou alaikoum

I am a Muslimah (female Muslim) and
Recently we have heard of people kidnapping children and sacrificing them to the evil for their selfish purpose ... and also we heard of the illuminati ... they also are sacrificing people to the evil ...
My question is that
If someone kidnaps me by force ...
And they sacrifice me  (killed me), would I go to hell?

I mean do they only sacrifice my body or also my soul
and if I was a good practising Muslim
would I go to hell
when they sacrifice me?

I hope I get the answer soon ... Jazakallah khair

Answer (score 2):

Oh, what it is claimed would definitely be wrong as:

> we have heard of people kidnapping children and sacrificing them to
>   the evil for their selfish purpose...and also we heard of the
>   illuminati ...they also are sacrificing people to the evil.. My
>   question is that If someone kidnaps me by force... and they sacrifice
>   me (killed me) Would I go to hell ?

Actually it is not so significant how will you be died or killed, but your Akherah fate (paradise or hell) would be definitely related to your Donya (world) practices, otherwise it would not be fair like what you remarked...

Answer (score 2):

Whether you are going to Heaven or hell depends on what you have done with your life, all the good deeds you have done. If willingly give your soul to the evil, which is more like a suicide, you will end up in hell.